# Escape space in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder

I am not able to execute the following code in Eclipse:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    String path="C:\\Users\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject
                = new ProcessBuilder("powershell",path);
    try {
        processBuilderObject.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am able to execute it if path is as `C:\\Users\\SendMailPS.ps1`. So the problem is with spaces, how can I solve this?

**Edit:** I tried like this as well

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    String path="C:\\Users\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell "+path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But no use. Then I tried directly from command prompt

```
>powershell
> C:\Users\SendMailPS.ps1
```

This gives me output. But following line gives me error

```
>powershell
> C:\Users\my dir\SendMailPS.ps1
```

error:

> C:\Users\my : The term 'C:\Users\my' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

Comment: i dont find any errors in your code.

Comment: I can see the output by getting a mail. If I use path without space I get mail otherwise I don't get.

Comment: I dont think space causes a problem.Well you can test it as i did.Create two files and name it like test0ne.txt and test one.txt.Try to write in both files.

Comment: you want me to write the output/result of the program in .txt?

Answer (score 2):

```
String path="C:\\Users\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject
            = new ProcessBuilder("powershell",path);
```

What you're actually doing here is to run a one-line powershell script which invokes your SendMailPS script. The one-line script is subject to powershell's script parsing, which is causing your problem.

Try running your script this way:

```
String path="C:\\Users\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject
            = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "-File", path);
```

This explicitly tells Powershell to run the specified file as a script.

Do *not* use string contatenation here:

```
// Don't do this
ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject
            = new ProcessBuilder("powershell -File " + path); // Don't do this
// Don't do this
```

Trying to run it this way will give you more trouble.